# How do I read a remote xlsx file in node JS?

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I have an xlsx file stored in a server and I wanna access it through my node.js web app. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score -2):

You should think about it as 2 steps
1. Download file from remote server
2. Use library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx to open that file